# wso2: Looking for XSLT transformation working example

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Can some one point me to a working example of xsl transformation using the proxy services xslt  mediator option.

Basically, my requirement is, i will have a request where i will get some data which determines the routing and after that from other elements of requested data i have to re frame soap request to trigger another bpel service.

Please let me know the better approach to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well use XSLT transformation in your sequence, using XSLT Mediator.

In your sequence file you can specify the XSLT file to tranform the request. Sample sequence code snippet:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SampleInterceptorSequence">
   <in>
      <log level="full" category="DEBUG">
         <property name="sequence" value="inSequence-Request Before XSLT" />
      </log>
      <xslt key="RequestTranformerXSLT" />
      <log level="full" category="DEBUG">
         <property name="sequence" value="inSequence-Request After XSLT" />
      </log>
      <send>
         <endpoint key="MyActualServiceEPR" />
      </send>
    </in>
```

Your xslt would contain the style for the actual request to be formed for hitting the end point reference.

Further if you can check this nice article of web service chaining to get a real time idea of xslt mediation.

[Web Service Chaining from WSO2 ESB Developers](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining)

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Find the sample below..

http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/message_mediation_samples.html#Sample8

Comment: IM trying to use it from Eclipse based developers studio... can you please let me know what component generates this definitions tag ?

Comment: I wish to understand where can i introduce the xslt transformation.
still now i was trying to create it in my proxy service file.

Comment: when you try to create a new proxyservice,within the sequence you need to add a child medtor..in the option panel you will find transform-->xslt mediator..

Comment: This link is dead.